# MySQL optimizing query through multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sugarcrm

I have problems with optimizing the following query to run acceptably fast:

```
SELECT
co_contracts_cstm.is_master_c,
co_contracts.id id
FROM co_contracts
    LEFT JOIN co_contracts_cstm ON co_contracts_cstm.id_c = 
co_contracts.id
WHERE co_contracts.deleted = 0 AND co_contracts_cstm.is_master_c = 1
ORDER BY co_contracts.document_name ASC, co_contracts.id DESC LIMIT 0,21
```

To give you some details: the co_contracts and co_contracts_cstm tables contain about 3M records each and they share primary keys, which I am joining them on. About 1M of these contracts have the is_master_c attribute equal to 1.

I have created indexes such as `(deleted, document_name, id)` on `co_contracts` which makes the query run very reasonably fast (about 4s), but only **IF** I remove the `is_master_c` WHERE condition. With it it runs for over a minute, which is too much.

I need this table join to be quickly orderable by several columns, `document_name` is just an example here. No matter what indexes I try on the `co_contracts_cstm` table, it is of no help, and the query still runs for over a minute.

I assume the problem is, that SQL probably sorts the full million records only to return 20 of the results. I guess a solution would be to only have one table (I am not quite sure why there are two), but it's something I shamely cannot do - it would conflict with an administration tool that controls the database. In a similiar way, I sort of cannot redesign the database as a whole.

If I add more constrains to the WHERE condition, the query becomes counterintuitivelly faster - I assume the main problem is, that through the filters I lose an index to sort with.

Edit: Adding an EXPLAIN

```
+----+-------------+-------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+--------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table             | type   | possible_keys                                       | key                 | key_len | ref                      | rows    | Extra                                    |
+----+-------------+-------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+--------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | co_contracts      | ref    | PRIMARY,idx_document_name_s                         | idx_document_name_s | 2       | const                    | 1251039 | Using where; Using index; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | co_contracts_cstm | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_master_c                                | PRIMARY             | 108     | sugarcrm.co_contracts.id |       1 | Using where                              |
+----+-------------+-------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+--------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+
```

For you to not be worried with filesort, it is claimed in EXPLAIN even in the query without the `is_master_c` WHERE condition (which is fast).

And the relevant indexes on co_contracts:

```
+--------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name                      | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| co_contracts |          0 | PRIMARY                       |            1 | id            | A         |     2502079 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| co_contracts |          1 | idx_document_name_s           |            1 | deleted       | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| co_contracts |          1 | idx_document_name_s           |            2 | document_name | A         |       32494 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| co_contracts |          1 | idx_document_name_s           |            3 | id            | A         |     2502079 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

And relevant indexes on co_contracts_cstm, to be complete:

```
+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table             | Non_unique | Key_name              | Seq_in_index | Column_name       | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| co_contracts_cstm |          0 | PRIMARY               |            1 | id_c              | A         |     2502364 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| co_contracts_cstm |          1 | idx_master_c          |            1 | id_c              | A         |     2502364 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| co_contracts_cstm |          1 | idx_master_c          |            2 | is_master_c       | A         |     2502364 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

(forcing the idx_master_c INDEX doesn't work, neither if it is in order `(id_c, is_master)` or `(is_master, id_c)`.

Comment: can you do `explain` and show us what all indexes `mysql` is using?

Comment: Added it to the question body.

Comment: If you could post schema definitions of both the tables and sample data it would be easy for us to replicate and let you know

Comment: The problem appears to be because of `is_master_c` column in `co_contracts` table. And you mentioned, close to 1M rows has it's value as 1. To me it appears like a boolean field and index can't be applied on it as mysql optimizer will look for full table scan.

Comment: If `is_master_c` column is a boolean field, you can try this `SELECT
co_contracts_cstm.is_master_c,
co_contracts.id id
FROM co_contracts
    LEFT JOIN co_contracts_cstm ON co_contracts_cstm.id_c = 
co_contracts.id
WHERE co_contracts.deleted = 0 AND co_contracts_cstm.is_master_c NOT 0
ORDER BY co_contracts.document_name ASC, co_contracts.id DESC LIMIT 0,21` This might improve performance to some extent. Can you check post the explain statement of above query?

Comment: @harshavmb: yes, it is merely a boolean field, it sounds like full table scanning is true, but really slow. The tables are much larger, actually, and it would be quite a thing to post that much data (plus, I can't, even test data are sensitive info). And the above query has performance and explain statement equal to what you see above.

Comment: Hmm., I actually expected some improvement as NOT performs better over =. But, that didn't work here. Are you sure it fetched same number of rows as yours?